# iCloud File size ionic V1

Tags: ionic-framework

get iCloud file size before uploading the file through file transfer plugin.
I able to upload the file through that path but cannot find the file size.

Working in android but not in iOS

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(Uri, 
                function(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {
                        console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
                        var size        = fileObj.size;
                        var megaSize    = size / MEGABYTE;
                        var roundedSize = Math.round( megaSize * 10 ) / 10;

                        console.log("roundedSize", roundedSize);
                        if(roundedSize < UPLOAD_LIMIT) { 
                            _fileUploadToServer(Uri, successCB, errorCB);
                        }
                        else {
                            showToast.snackbarCustom($filter('translate')('FILE_SIZE_NOT_ALLOWED'),kbUp);
                        }
                    },
                    function (error) {});
                }, function (error) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

in iCloud the path has /private prepended. Replace it with file:// to get the file size similarly as android